# Matrix multiplication error when I tried to build the neural network from scratch

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

When I learned about mathematical working of neural network I tried to build it from scratch using Numpy. The neural network structure I tried to build was input_layer with 3 nodes -> hidden_layer_1 with 2 nodes -> hidden_layer_2 with 2 nodes -> output_layer with 1 node. Both of the hidden layers use ReLu activation function, and the output layer uses Sigmoid activation function. Here is the data set : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xP6BvneSdG5SoXL1ADp0veZMSrOcFlQc/view?usp=drive_linkThe code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

W1 = np.random.rand(2, 3) # Weight matrices
W2 = np.random.rand(2, 2)
W3 = np.random.rand(1, 2)

B1 = np.random.rand(2, 1) # Bias vectors
B2 = np.random.rand(2, 1)
B3 = np.random.rand(1, 1)

ReLu = lambda x : np.maximum(x, 0)
Sigmoid = lambda x : 1/ (1+np.exp(-x))

def forward_prop(inputs):

    Z1 = W1@inputs + B1
    A1 = ReLu(Z1)
    
    Z2 = W2@A1 + B2
    A2 = ReLu(Z2)
    
    Z3 = W3@A2 + B3
    A3 = Sigmoid(Z3)
        
    return Z1, A1, Z2, A2, Z3, A3

d_relu = lambda x : x>0
d_sigmoid = lambda x : np.exp(-x) / (1+np.exp(-x))**2

def back_prop(Z1, A1, Z2, A2, Z3, A3, X, Y):
    
    #derivatives
    dC_dA3 = 2*A3 - 2*Y
    
    dA3_dZ3 = d_sigmoid(Z3)
    dZ3_dW3 = A2
    dZ3_dB3 = 1
    dZ3_dA2 = W3
    
    dA2_dZ2 = d_relu(Z2)
    dZ2_dW2 = A1
    dZ2_dB2 = 1
    dZ2_dA1 = W2
    
    dA1_dZ1 = d_relu(Z1)
    dZ1_dW1 = X
    dZ1_dB1 = 1
    
    dC_dW3 = dC_dA3 @ dA3_dZ3 @ dZ3_dW3.T
    dC_dB3 = dC_dA3 @ dA3_dZ3 * dZ3_dB3
    dC_dA2 = dC_dA3 @ dA3_dZ3 @ dZ3_dA2
    dC_dW2 = dC_dA2 @ dA2_dZ2 @ dZ2_dW2.T
    dC_dB2 = dC_dA2 @ dA2_dZ2 * dZ2_dB2
    dC_dA1 = dC_dA2 @ dA2_dZ2 @ dZ2_dA1 # Problem is here
    dC_dW1 = dC_dA1 @ dA1_dZ1 @ dZ1_dW1.T
    dC_dB1 = dC_dA1 @ dA1_dZ1 * dZ1_dB1
    
    return dC_dW1, dC_dB1, dC_dW2, dC_dB2, dC_dW3, dC_dB3

data = pd.read_csv('light_dark_font_training_set.csv')
x = data.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = data.iloc[:, -1].values

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=1/3)

n = x_train.shape[0]
L = 0.05
epochs = 100_000

for i in range(epochs):

    idx = np.random.choice(n, 1, replace=False)
    x_sample = x_train[idx].transpose()
    y_sample = y_train[idx]
    
    z1, a1, z2, a2, z3, a3 = forward_prop(x_sample)
    w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3 = back_prop(z1, a1, z2, a2, z3, a3, x_sample, y_sample)
    
    W1 -= L*w1
    W2 -= L*w2
    W3 -= L*w3
    
    B1 -= L*b1
    B2 -= L*b2
    B3 -= L*b3
    
    if i%10000 == 0:
        print(i)
```

When I tried running the above program it shows the following value error, which says that the matrix dimensions are not matched for matrix multiplication. At first I thought I had some problems with the partial derivatives in back propagation but as for my as knowledge it looks fine to me.

Why does this happen and how to resolve it?

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11036/3060626554.py in <module>
      6 
      7     z1, a1, z2, a2, z3, a3 = forward_prop(x_sample)
----> 8     w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3 = back_prop(z1, a1, z2, a2, z3, a3, x_sample, y_sample)
      9 
     10     W1 -= L*w1

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11036/566612658.py in back_prop(Z1, A1, Z2, A2, Z3, A3, X, Y)
     22     dC_dW2 = dC_dA2 @ dA2_dZ2 @ dZ2_dW2.T
     23     dC_dB2 = dC_dA2 @ dA2_dZ2 * dZ2_dB2
---> 24     dC_dA1 = dC_dA2 @ dA2_dZ2 @ dZ2_dA1# Problem is here
     25     dC_dW1 = dC_dA1 @ dA1_dZ1 @ dZ1_dW1.T
     26     dC_dB1 = dC_dA1 @ dA1_dZ1 * dZ1_dB1

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc     signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 1)
```

Comment: issue with the matrix multiplication in the backward propagation function - (dC_dA1)

Answer (score 1):

try like this :

```
def back_prop(Z1, A1, Z2, A2, Z3, A3, X, Y):

# derivatives
dC_dA3 = 2 * (A3 - Y)

dA3_dZ3 = d_sigmoid(Z3)
dZ3_dW3 = A2
dZ3_dB3 = 1
dZ3_dA2 = W3

dA2_dZ2 = d_relu(Z2)
dZ2_dW2 = A1
dZ2_dB2 = 1
dZ2_dA1 = W2

dA1_dZ1 = d_relu(Z1)
dZ1_dW1 = X
dZ1_dB1 = 1

# Use element-wise multiplication for dC_dA1
dC_dA1 = dC_dA2 * (dA2_dZ2 @ dZ2_dA1.T)

dC_dW3 = dC_dA3 @ (dA3_dZ3 * dZ3_dW3).T
dC_dB3 = dC_dA3 * dA3_dZ3 * dZ3_dB3
dC_dW2 = dC_dA2 @ (dA2_dZ2 * dZ2_dW2).T
dC_dB2 = dC_dA2 * dA2_dZ2 * dZ2_dB2
dC_dW1 = dC_dA1 @ (dA1_dZ1 * dZ1_dW1).T
dC_dB1 = dC_dA1 * dA1_dZ1 * dZ1_dB1

return dC_dW1, dC_dB1, dC_dW2, dC_dB2, dC_dW3, dC_dB3
```

Comment: you missed out the dC_dA2